# when i set worker time out in gunicorn for Django Application, other users are not able to access the application

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, wsgi

I have a django application running on Gunicorn and Nginx. There is one request in application which takes 10 min to load the page [There is lot of data to process], i have increased the worker time to 1200 sec for Gunicorn to make it take sufficient time to load the page. it works fine but until that request is getting processed other users are not able to access the application gives :

504 Gateway Time-out
nginx/1.21.4

This is my DOCKER

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    command: python manage.py makemigrations /
    && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput/
     && python manage.py crontab add /
     && exec gunicorn DrDNAC.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 1200"
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:13.0-alpine
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static:
```

This is nginx:

```
upstream app {
    server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://app;
        proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    }
    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you check if nginx container can resolve web name to IP address?
{docker exec -it nginx_container_name /bin/bash}
and run 'ping web' if you don't have ping in container you must install it by 
1. apt update
2.apt install iputils-ping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen because the amount of workers is not sufficient.

Try to increase the amount by adding `--workers=4` to the gunicorn call.

```
gunicorn DrDNAC.wsgi:application --workers=4 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 1200
```

You can find more informations under the following link:
https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-processes

In addition you can also increase the amount of threads by using `--threads 4`

Comment: it worked, Thank You.